# What's wrong with EmbeddedHTML now?

Tags: bugs, formatting, interoperability, wolfram-cloud

**Bug introduced in $CloudVersion V1.38 or earlier and fixed in V1.46**

> [...] I checked and reproduced your issue, and have passed along a report to our developers on the same [...]
>
> [CASE:3973757]

---

Here's an example from docs:

```
CloudDeploy[
    Manipulate[
        EmbeddedHTML @ StringTemplate["
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html><body><h2 style=\"color:`1`\">
            This text is `1`.
          </h2></body></html>
        "][color],
        {
            {color, "red"},
            {"red" -> Red, "green" -> Green, "blue" -> Blue}
        },
        ControlPlacement -> Left, ContentSize -> 350
    ],
    Permissions -> "Public"
]
```

[image]

It used to work, any tips how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem seems to be fixed in 1.45 `$CloudVersion`.

I'm not aware of any workaround for earlier versions but it should not matter unless you use Private Cloud and somehow got stuck with older version.