# Upload notebook to the Cloud and add a download hyperlink in separate cloud objects

Tags: gui-construction, files-and-directories, wolfram-cloud, web-access

[*cross posted on community.wolfram.com*](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1236258)

Title say it all, I want to export _Notebook to cloud as a .nb file and make it available to download via hyperlink in different places.

This is rather a code-review question, because I have the working code.

The problem is that it does not feel idiomatic:

```
(*uploading notebook*)
co = CloudExport[
  ExportString[
    Notebook[{Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Defer[1 + 1], "Input"]}]
  , "NB"
  ]
, "Text"
, "test/notebook.nb"
]
```

```
(*cloud object with a download link*)
With[
  { hyperlink = StringTemplate[
      "<a href = \"``\" download>Download notebook</a>"
    ] @ First @ co
  }
, CloudDeploy[
    Column[{ EmbeddedHTML[hyperlink], Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1}]}]
  , "test/fileHyperlink"
  ]
]
```

I want to address the following issues:

- Exporting .nb via ExportString + Text.

  Straightforward `CloudExport` as "NB" or `CloudDeploy` would be better but I can't restrict it to not being treated as a *Cloud Notebook* and what is fetched otherwise is an html file.
- Download link

  It is nice that `EmbeddCode` [almost](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160101/5478) works, but one would expect `Hyperlink` to do that. I failed to find the correct syntax for it, e.g., `Hyperlink[lbl, File[url]]` redirects to plain text .nb in a browser.

So, unless I missed something and someone provides a cleaner way, I will move the code to an answer later.